# How configure Stanford QNMinimizer to get similar results as scipy.optimize.minimize L-BFGS-B

Tags: java, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, stanford-nlp

I want to configurate the QN-Minimizer from Stanford Core NLP Lib to get nearly similar optimization results as scipy optimize L-BFGS-B implementation or get a standard L-BFSG configuration that is suitable for the most things. I set the standard paramters as follow:

The python example I want to copy:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(neuralNetworkCost, input_theta, method = 'L-BFGS-B', jac = True)
```

My try to do the same in Java:

```
QNMinimizer qn = new QNMinimizer(10,true) ;
qn.terminateOnMaxItr(batch_iterations);
//qn.setM(10);
output = qn.minimize(neuralNetworkCost, 1e-5, input,15000);
```

What I need is a solid and general L-BFSG configuration, that is suitable to solve most problems.

I m also not sure, if I need to set some of these parameters for standard L-BFGS configuration:

```
useAveImprovement = ?;
useRelativeNorm = ?;
useNumericalZero = ?;
useEvalImprovement = ?;
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I m new on that field.

Resources for Information:
**Stanford Core NLP QNMinimizer:**
http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.2/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/QNMinimizer.html#setM-int-
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/QNMinimizer.java

**Scipy Optimize L-BFGS-B:**
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `What I need is a solid and general L-BFSG configuration, that is suitable to solve most problems.` - If there was a set of arguments that works very well for almost all functions, those arguments would be the default arguments, don't you think? Optimizing arbitrary, non-convex functions can be very difficult to impossible. The parameters often matter and have to be tailored to the problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I thought that something like that would come :-D However do you think my parameters are equal to scipy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should be just fine. (Have you actually had any problems with it?)

Setting termination both on max iterations and max function evaluations is probably overkill, so you might omit the last argument to `qn.minimize()`, but it seems from the documentation that scipy does use both with a default value of 15000.

In general, using the robustOptions (with a second argument of `true` as you do) should give a reliable minimizer, similar to the `pgtol` convergence criterion of scipy. The other options are for special situations or just to experiment with how they work.